# D-Link Reset firmware to factory settings firmware failed

Tags: router, wireless-router, cable-modem

My Device is D-Link DIR 850L B1 firmware Et-1.02 was upgraded to DIR850LB1_FW220WWb03 successfully, after upgrade the configuration were also reset.

I have backup of saved settings file config.DAT from my previous version which I tried to import to the new version, but the import failed because of the old format no longer supported in new version (config.bin). Now I'm not able to connect to internet.  My provider is local cable network provider. I have a screenshot of old settings,
I manually tried to config PPoE connection with my username and password, but it is not able to get connection in new version. I decided to reset the firmware to factory settings, I downloaded DIR-850L_firmware_103.zip old version, and I put router in recovery mode, uploaded the firmware file, after 100% upload complete its showing error, Upgrade failed, 
I need help on resetting the firmware.

Comment: Try the emergency flashing procedure when firmware has failed.   http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=44909.0

Comment: config files cannot be restored to a different firmware. Since you upgraded the firmware the old config file cannot be restored. Did you try a hard reset of the router using the reset button?

Comment: By the way, did you opt for ‘Clone PC MAC address’ in earlier firmware version? If yes, then the MAC address might have been reset to original factory value for the router after firmware upgrade and that might be one of the possible reasons, you are not getting connected to Internet on PPPoE after firmware upgrade. There might be other reasons too, this is just one of the possibilities.

Comment: mac clone also tried, it didnt connect

Comment: recovery mode firmware failed

Comment: What OS & Browser do you have? It's my observation that for firmware upgrade/downgrade, certain combination of OS & Browser works well. e.g. My Dlink DIR 615 firmware upload works best with Windows 7 & Mozilla and fails on Windows 10 & Chrome, especially when in Recovery Mode.

Comment: after upgraded to 2.20 I could downgrade again to DIR850LB1_FW207WWb05.bin in recovery mode, But I want to downgrade to its factory firmware B1 v1.02 the which i'm not able find on the internet

Comment: With FW v2.07 are you able to connect to the Internet? If not, in your original PC that was wired to the router, try creating an Internet Connection PPPoE and try connecting directly to the ISP bypassing the router, if you can't may be it's time to also check with the ISP.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it connected to internet, I did a reset, set mac id clone then tried to connect again with a my username and password.